# Form won't submit after validation

Tags: validation

I want to submit this form once its validate field, but it wont submit to the next page. I guess there something I need to add on jQuery.

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    //$(this).trigger('submit');
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

HTML:

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="save.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="exampleFormControlInput20">Info</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea25" rows="3" placeholder="Fill in your info"></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Fill in this field.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer text-end">
    <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-success active" type="submit" title="Submit Info">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger active" type="reset" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have no jQuery here, except for the line that is commented out?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    //$(this).trigger('submit');
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" action="save.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="exampleFormControlInput20">Info</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea25" rows="3" placeholder="Fill in your info" required minlength="10"></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Fill in this field.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer text-end">
    <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-success active" type="submit" title="Submit Info">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger active" type="reset" title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When it passes validation you need to submit the form yourself.

```
if (form.checkValidity() === false) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();       
} else {
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: i tried adding form.submit like ur suggestion and it going to the next page but my form not validate. seems like its bypass the validation.